# Transforming a particular element of DataRow item Array?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Currently, the application code reads directly from the excel giving me a **DataTable**. It has column with month's property(the last value of data row's Item Array).
In db, the months are stored as an int value.

I am not able to think of the approach apart from using LINQ tool to just change/transform the last value of each data row's ItemArray and change monthname to monthnumber and then forming a new data table, before running the query.

```
DataTable dt = obj.ToDataTable();
dt = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row.ItemArray.Select(x => ???)).CopyToDataTable() //stuck here
```

Comment: var results = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<string>(0)).ToArray();  The results has less columns than original table so you cannot use CopyToDataTable();

Comment: Do you know the columnName which represents the Month from Excel Sheet? Do you want to Change from MonthName to MonthNumber in the sameplace or you are creating a new column for MonthNumber?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes I do. In the same place so it gets right stored in the db where table has the month(int) column type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your issue easier by using `foreach` loop than LINQ.

```
DataTable dataTable = obj.ToDataTable();

// Store the column index of the Month column
var monthColIndex = dataTable.Columns.Count - 1; // Index of Last Column
    
    foreach(var dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        var row = dataRow as DataRow;
        // Get Month Number from the Month Name column from each row.
        var monthNumber = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames.ToList().IndexOf(row[monthColIndex].ToString()) + 1;
        // Assign monthNumber to the last column value in each row.
        row[monthColIndex] = monthNumber;
    }
```

I hope this will help your solve your issue.